# Any idea where chartingprimitives:Edgepanel has gone in Silverlight 5?

Tags: charts, silverlight-5.0

I am (trying) to code a Silverlight 5 application to display some Charts.  I have installed the Silverlight 5 Toolkit from Codeplex (Dec 2011 version) and I have customized the Chart Control template to move the legend to the bottom of the Chart, but - as soon as the Legend re-position started working - the ChartArea itself would not display any data.

To try and resolve this problem (no ChartArea data appearing) I have included the definition

xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

but when I try to modify the template to use the tag

< chartingprimitives:Edgepanel >

Visual Web Developer 2012 says it cannot be found ...

Does anybody have any idea where this tag has gone?  Has it been moved into another include, or has it been replaced by  tag as some Chart Control Template examples show ???

Answer (score 0):

```
   <toolkit:Chart
                    x:Name="barStyledChart"
                    Foreground="#FF579ED4"
                    Style="{StaticResource GreenFxChartStyle}"
                    FontSize="8"
                    Width="290"
                    Height="170"
                    BorderThickness="0">
                    <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
                        <toolkit:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="X" Interval="1">
                            <toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF579ED4"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                        </toolkit:LinearAxis>
                        <toolkit:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Minimum="0" Maximum="200">
                            <toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF032F50"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </toolkit:LinearAxis.GridLineStyle>
                        </toolkit:LinearAxis>
                    </toolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <toolkit:ColumnSeries Background="#FF53C023" 
            AnimationSequence="FirstToLast" 
            DependentValuePath="X" IndependentValuePath="Y">
            <toolkit:ColumnSeries.ItemsSource>
                <PointCollection>
                    <Point>100,2000</Point>
                    <Point>105,2001</Point>
                    <Point>98,2002</Point>
                    <Point>88,2003</Point>
                    <Point>150,2004</Point>
                    <Point>125,2005</Point>
                    <Point>93,2006</Point>
                    <Point>112,2007</Point>
                    <Point>145,2008</Point>
                    <Point>165,2009</Point>
                    <Point>173,2010</Point>
                    <Point>168,2011</Point>
                    <Point>160,2012</Point>
                    <Point>164,2013</Point>
                    <Point>158,2014</Point>                                                                     
                </PointCollection>
            </toolkit:ColumnSeries.ItemsSource>
                        <toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                            <Grid Width="10">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF53C023" Opacity=".8"></Rectangle>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
                </toolkit:Chart>




<Application
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization"
xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.ProgressionSequenceData" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightChartScratchpad.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <SampleData:ProgressionSequenceData x:Key="ProgressionSequenceData" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

    <Style x:Key="GreenFxChartStyle" TargetType="toolkit:Chart" >
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />

        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.352,1.144" StartPoint="0.352,-0.161">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0585D6" Offset="0.268"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF01336E" Offset="0.847"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>         

      <Setter Property="TitleStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="toolkit:Title">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="LegendStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="toolkit:Legend">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="ChartAreaStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="Panel">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="75" />
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="PlotAreaStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Chart">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <toolkit:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                <!-- Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <toolkit:Legend x:Name="Legend" Header="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                  <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                    <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF032F50" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" />
                  </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Mmm ... not quite.  Even with

Comment: Even with all your declarations at the front EXACTLY as you have them, I still get                                                                                                                                    The type 'chartingprimitives:EdgePanel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.                                                                                                                                I already have added a reference to System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Don't care anymore more now - dumped all Silverlight development over 2 years ago ..